# Compute number of word distance of 1 for every word in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, runtime

For each string in a list, I need to find the number of strings in that list that are one levenshtein-distance away. The levenshtein-distance is smallest number of character substitutions, additions, or removals necessary to derive one word from another. For illustration, please see the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
'word':['can', 'cans', 'canse', 'canpe', 'canp', 'camp'],
'code':['k@n', 'k@n}', 'k@(z', np.nan, 'k@()', np.nan]})

  word  code
0 can    k@n
1 cans  k@n}
2 canse k@(z
3 canpe
4 canp  k@()
5 camp
```

My current implementation is way too slow:

```
from Levenshtein import distance as lev

df = df.fillna('')

# get unique strings
wordAll = df['word'].dropna().to_list()
codeAll = list(set(df['code'].dropna().to_list()))

# prepare dataframe for storage
df['wordLev'] = np.nan
df['codeLev'] = np.nan

# find neighbors
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    i=0
    j=0

    # get word and code
    word = row['word']
    code = row['code']

    # remove word and code from all-strings-list
    wordSubset = [w for w in wordAll if w != word]
    codeSubset = [c for c in codeAll if c != code]

    # compute number of neighbors
    for item in wordSubset:
        if lev(word, item) == 1:
            i += 1
    for item in codeSubset:
        if lev(code, item) == 1:
            j += 1

    # add number of neighbors to df
    df.loc[df['code'] == code, 'wordLev'] = i
    if code != '':
        df.loc[df['code'] == code, 'codeLev'] = j
    else:
        df.loc[df['code'] == code, 'codeLev'] = ''

df

  word  code wordLev codeLev
0 can    k@n       2       1  
1 cans  k@n}       3       1
2 canse k@(z       2       1
3 canpe            2
4 canp  k@()       3       1
5 camp             1
```

How can I speed it up? The DataFrame has ~500k rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code seems to be ~5x faster than your code at 1.8ms vs 9.6ms (at least on the `df` you've provided).

```
df = df.fillna('')
df['wordLev'] = [sum(1 for item in df['word'] if item!=word and lev(word, item)==1) for word in df['word']]
df['codeLev'] = [sum(1 for item in df['code'] if item!=code and lev(code, item)==1) or '' for code in df['code']]
```

This code is really very similar to yours. Biggest difference is that instead of creating `wordSubset` or `codeSubset` and then iterating over them again to apply the levenshtein distance function, it does it in all in a single generator expression. Since you're checking each word with every word in the column, you can't escape a double loop imo.